# JasperReports: Generating the report in XLS Format

Tags: jasper-reports

I am working with *JasperReports 4.5.0* and i want to generate the report in *XLS* format. The report is generating fine. But I have set the background color for images. This background color is not displaying in *XLS* format. Remaining PDF, CSV, HTML, DOC formats it is displaying fine.

What might be the problem?

Comment: But now you can improve your rate

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11372632/jasper-report-exported-to-excel-format-is-not-displaying-the-background-colour/11972505#11972505